Does HydroSheds (https://www.hydrosheds.org) provides labels?
I've been following a simple tutorial that uses HydroShed files. Everything went smoothly, but I would like to also add labels for some of the rivers plotted (eg: Orinoco). Anyone with experience using that HydroShed files or any alternative source from which I could get those labels?

If HydroSHEDS is open data then I think the place to ask about its compilation and that of similar datasets is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Alright, I just read the FAQ:
Do the rivers, lakes, and basins in HydroRIVERS, HydroLAKES, and HydroBASINS have names?
It is currently not possible to identify the name of each waterbody or watershed in HydroRIVERS, HydroLAKES, or HydroBASINS. The HydroATLAS database provides country areas for the year 2012 from the Global Administrative Areas (GADM) database v2.0.
